# Как работают события в C#

Tags: c#, события

Предположим, в одном объекте у нас есть событие, которое инициируется при некоторых условиях. В другом объекте есть множество подписчиков на это одно событие. Когда событие произошло, происходит проход по обработчикам события и определяется тот, который должен отработать.

Будет ли обработчик работать асинхронно? Нужно ли использовать *lock*-и и блокировать куски кода, чтобы другие обработчики туда не зашли? И вообще, будут ли работать другие обработчики, пока один из них работает?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Значит так.

Для начала, событие будет послано *всем* подписчикам, одному за другим. Это происходит **синхронно**, как часть отправки события. Порядок вызова подписчиков не определён, следующий подписчик будет запущен только когда предыдущий полностью отработал (за исключением `async`-методов, разумеется!).

События доставляются в том потоке, в котором они инициируются. Это значит, что если всё происходит в UI-потоке, то блокировки бессмысленны, многопоточного доступа нет.

Это также означает, что код обработчика событий обязан быть *быстрым*: если ваш обработчик события делает что-то длинное, при этом остальные обработчики будут ждать, пока первый обработчик закончит, и только тогда получат управление. Хуже того, если пока работает обработчик события, этот поток блокируется, и доставка всех других событий приостанавливается.

Тем не менее, есть неприятный момент: если вы (не дай бог!) почему-то в обработчике события запускаете модальный диалог, то в нём запускается внутренний цикл обработки событий, и таким образом при ещё бегущем обработчике событий вполне может прийти следующее событие, и обработчик выполнится рекурсивно! Вы не сможете предотвратить это при помощи блокировок, потому что рекурсия происходит в том же потоке. Просто *никогда* не делайте ничего длинного блокирующего в обработчике события, иначе неприятностей рано или поздно не избежать.

Если вы пользуетесь современным C#, имеет смысл сделать async-обработчик события, чтобы он «отдавал» выполнение другим обработчикам при первом же `await`'е. Таким образом, пока один из обработчиков «висит» в `await`'е, начнёт выполняться следующий. Имейте в виду, что при этом обработчик события станет асинхронным, и его точно так же сможет «догнать» следующий обработчик того же или следующего экземпляра события.

Или если вы не пользуетесь `async`/`await` (например, потому, что работаете с версией языка эпохи палеолита), то длинную обработку лучше выгружать в другой поток (например, `BackgroundWorker`, если вы пользуетесь каким-нибудь UI-фреймворком, или TPL).

---

**Дополнение:** Как справедливо замечает в комментариях @Антон Буторин, если один из обработчиков события синхронно выбрасывает исключение, то запуск остальных обработчиков также не происходит, а отправление события завершается (с этим же исключением). Для `async void`-обработчиков, если исключение выбрасывается в асинхронной части, это может и вовсе привести к падению приложения. Отсюда [совет, граничащий по силе с правилом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3114603/276994): обработчики событий не должны выбрасывать исключения.

---

**Обновление:**

В обычном случае я бы советовал делать так:

1. Подписка на события, отписка от них и посылка самих событий должны происходить в UI-потоке.
2. Код посылки сообщения в таком случае [стандартный](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/awbftdfh.aspx):

   ```
   public class UserLoginEventArgs : EventArgs
   {
       public User User { get; private set; }
       internal UserLoginEventArgs(User user) { this.User = user; }
   }

   public event EventHandler<NewUserEventArgs> UserLogin;
   void RaiseUserLoginEvent(User user)
   {
       if (UserLogin != null)
           UserLogin(this, new UserLoginEventArgs(user));
   }
   ```

   Заметьте, что вам не нужна обычно используемая техника копирования `UserLogin` в локальную переменную.
3. Асинхронность, если она нужна, достигается на стороне обработчика сообщения:

   ```
   // синхронный обработчик
   void OnUserLogin(object sender, UserLoginEventArgs args)
   {
       activeUsers.Add(args.User);
   }
   ```

   ```
   // асинхронный обработчик
   async void OnUserLogin(object sender, UserLoginEventArgs args)
   {
       var user = args.User;
       if (!punishedUsers.Contain(user))
           return;
       await SendUserMessage(user, NotAllowedToLogInText);
       await LogoutUser(user);
   }
   ```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное за пояснение!! Очень здорово и понятно описываете. А вы не подскажете, как делать лучше/правильнее: вызывать обработчик в новом потоке(из пула) или запускать его асинхронно через  async/await? И еще, если Вам не сложно, не могли бы вы продемонстрировать, как сделать async обработчик события.(просто не очень понятно, асинхронно вызывается метод с логикой обработки в методе обработчике или же сам обработчик)

Comment: @user3661584: обновил ответ

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил, что если в обработчике события происходит исключение, то остальные синхронные обработчики уже не выполнятся, а в асинхронном обработчике это в некоторых случаях может привести к "срезанию" приложения, поэтому обработчики в большинстве случаев должны "ловить" свои исключения.

Comment: *если вы не пользуетесь async/await (например, потому, что работаете с версией языка эпохи палеолита)* - или потому, что логика требует мгновенной реакции на события. Сразу гнать на язык не стоит.

Comment: @Vesper: Вы прочитали только часть предложения. Дальше написано: «_то длинную обработку лучше выгружать в другой поток_». Таким образом, речь идёт о случае, когда необходима  длительная обработка, а не мгновенная реакция.

Comment: Интересно, как лучше проектировать событийную модель в случаях, когда логика обработчиков  не занимает длительного времени. Стоит ли в этом случае связываться с многопоточностью и тратить время на выделение и синхронизацию потоков нежели работать в одном потоке?

Comment: @Sleeeper: На мой вкус, если обработчики событий быстрые, пусть работают синхронно. В любом случае вы всегда потом можете сделать async-обработчик, это никак (ну, почти никак) не повлияет на архитектуру.