# Как из асинхронного потока передать число в progressBar?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, mailkit

Как из асинхронного потока передать число в компонент progressBar? //

```
// Сводка:
//     Asynchronously get the specified message.
//
// Параметры:
//   uid:
//     The UID of the message.
//
//   cancellationToken:
//     The cancellation token.
//
//   progress:
//     The progress reporting mechanism.
//
// Возврат:
//     The message.
//
// Примечания.
//     Asynchronously gets the specified message.
Task<MimeMessage> GetMessageAsync(UniqueId uid, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken), ITransferProgress progress = null);
```

---

```
private async void DgvMessages_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        buttonDeleteMessage.Enabled = true;
        labelAttachments.Visible = false;
        progressBar.Visible = true;
        if (e.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            await _openFolder.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
            var messageUid = UniqueId.Parse(((DataGridView)sender).CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            TransferProgress progress = new TransferProgress(progressBar);
            var message = _openFolder.GetMessageAsync(messageUid, new CancellationToken(), progress).Result;
            // other code
            }
        }
    }
```

Класс TransferProgress

```
using MailKit;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace E_mail_client
{
    class TransferProgress : ITransferProgress
    {
        private ProgressBar progressBar;

        public TransferProgress(ProgressBar progressBar)
        {
            this.progressBar = progressBar;
        }

        public void Report(long bytesTransferred, long totalSize)
        {
            var size = (bytesTransferred * 100) / totalSize;
        }

        public void Report(long bytesTransferred)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему бы не использовать стандартный [Progress<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте события для обновления статуса вашего `ProgressBar`. Минимальная реализация `ITransferProgress` для .NET 4.5+ может выглядеть примерно так:

```
public class TransferProgress : ITransferProgress
{
    private long _bytesTransferred;
    private long _totalSize;

    public event EventHandler<double> ProgressChanged;

    public double Percents
    {
        get { return (double) _bytesTransferred / _totalSize * 100d; }
    }

    void ITransferProgress.Report(long bytesTransferred, long totalSize)
    {
        _bytesTransferred = bytesTransferred;
        _totalSize = totalSize;
        OnProgressChanged();
    }

    void ITransferProgress.Report(long bytesTransferred)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    protected virtual void OnProgressChanged()
    {
        var handler = Volatile.Read(ref ProgressChanged);
        if (handler != null) handler(this, Percents);
    }
}
```

Затем просто подпишитесь на событие `ProgressChanged` и обновляйте свойство `Value` вашего `ProgressBar`.

Запомните! Никогда не следует передавать UI-контролы в методы классов бизнес-логики, т.к. тогда появляется лишняя зависимость от UI. Вам необходимо чётко разделять вашу бизнес-логику (классы для работы с MailKit API) и UI (там где находятся формы и прочее).

---

Подробнее о механизме событий в .NET:

1. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/articles/csharp/events-overview
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/awbftdfh.aspx
3. [Как работают события в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436184/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-c/436185#436185)

Comment: Немного не понятна эта фраза "Затем просто подпишитесь на событие ProgressChanged..."

Comment: А почему не стандартный `ProgressChanged?.Invoke`?

Comment: @VladD да, null propagation operator тоже является потокобезопасным и работает с копией хендлера на уровне IL, так что вполне можно использовать и его, кому как нравится))

Comment: @Denis ну вот так: `tp.ProgressChanged += (sender, e) => { progressBar.Value = e; };`     см. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms366768.aspx

Comment: @Denis наверняка на ruSO был вопрос о событиях где описано понятным языком как они работают.

Comment: @Nikita вроде бы разобрался но теперь появилась проблема в том что  ProgressBar не заполняется а форма висит.

Comment: @Denis скорее всего вы где-то блокируете UI поток, поэтому ваша форма фризится.

Comment: @Nikita вот код https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5iMp/hF5QF7Mt9

https://github.com/DenisGlod/emailclient
Подскажите что не так.

Comment: @Denis `var message = _openFolder.GetMessageAsync(messageUid, new CancellationToken(), progress).Result;` вот тут блокировка, это синхронный вызов. Нужно так: `var message = await _openFolder.GetMessageAsync(messageUid, new CancellationToken(), progress);`

Comment: @Nikita спасибо, не заметил

Comment: @Nikita но progressBar все равно не заполняется

Comment: @Denis сделайте экземпляр TransferProgress полем _progress, затем в конструкторе формы выполните подписку один раз.  ` _progress.ProgressChanged += (s, percent) => {BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) (() => progressBar.Value = percent)); };` Не нужно подписываться много раз.

Comment: @Nikita появилась проблема прогресс приходит либо 0 либо 100, промежуточные числа не приходят. GitHub обновил

Comment: @Denis ну да, не нужно было менять код класса `TransferProgress`, приведенный в моём ответе на неправильный. Кастаните `double` в `int` уже при непосредственном присвоении:`BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) (() => progressBar.Value = (int)percent));`